# How to vectorize vectors of points

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a bunch of points (i.e. (x,y)) and I would like to isolate the ones that outside a unit circle. The condition is simple, one needs to to perform this inequality for all points

```
(x^2 + y^2) <= 1
```

In my case, x and y are vectors. I need to vectorize this problem. I can solve it through looping but I need to avoid this approach. Any suggestions? Something like this

```
if (x.^2 + y.^2) <= 1
    inside the circle
else
    outside the circle 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
x_in = x(x.^2 + y.^ <= 1);
y_in = y(x.^2 + y.^2 <= 1);
```

Builds `x_in` and `y_in` as the subset of `x` and `y`, for which that condition holds.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Is it the missing 2 after y.^ on the first line? Kind of hard to know without any details ...